# TS ERROR: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined' ts(2722)

Tags: typescript, types, typeerror

I have the following problem:
*Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined' ts(2722)*

Example code:

```
class Foo {
    bar?: () => void
    configure(bar: () => void) {
        this.bar = bar
    }
    
    isConfigured(): boolean {
        return !!(this.bar)
    }
  
    foo() {
        if(!this.isConfigured()) throw new Error("...")
        this.bar()
    }

}
```

The error happens here:

```
this.bar()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the Non-null assertion operator(`!`). This operator tells the compiler that you are sure that this property has a value even though it is declared nullable. It will look like this:

```js
    foo() {
        if (!this.isConfigured()) throw new Error("...")
        this.bar!()
    }
```

Another way to do this is to define a user-defined type guard (See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to learn more about user-defined type guards):

```js
class Foo {
    bar?: () => void
    configure(bar: () => void) {
        this.bar = bar
    }

    isConfigured(): this is { bar: () => void } {
                 // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This is type guard
        return !!(this.bar)
    }

    foo() {
        if (!this.isConfigured()) throw new Error("...")
        this.bar()
    }
}
```